# C# Cant to download JDK15

Tags: c#

I'm trying to download JDK15 but i downloading 5307 bytes but this are not the JDK15

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{

    wc.DownloadFileAsync(new System.Uri(
       "https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/15.0.1%2B9/51f4f36ad4ef43e39d0dfdbaf6549e32/jdk-15.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe"),
                Path.Combine(directoryPackagesPath, "jdk.exe")
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You downloaded a web page instructing you how to access the download:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly download that file. If you open it in another browser, or a incognito/private window, you will see this message:

> Sorry!
>
> In order to download products from Oracle Technology Network you must
> agree to the OTN license terms.

If you open the downloaded file, most likely it's an HTML with this message.

Answer (score 0):

It is illegal, but if you want learn how to do it for some CTF etc.:

1. Get query what is send after accepting licence  by dev tools in your browser.
2. Send the exact same query by `HttpClient` and get cookies from response.
3. Use this cookies to get the file.

If you want this particular version, you can attach it (if licence allows you to do that) to your program by using installer, by resources or even as normal file in output directory.